# PHP turn off errors - in one file only

Tags: php, error-handling

I am well aware about `error_reporting(0);` & `ini_set('display_errors', "Off");` to make error messages go away.

What would be an appropriate way to do this -  for a specific file or part of code only?
Surpressing errors with @'s seems like a bad idea since it apparently slows the code down...

The reason? We have a number of memcached servers in a development LAN that is really unreliable due to the network settings, thereby we are recieving errors multiple times every hour and there's nothing we can do about it except stop using memcache or turning off errors for the whole application, which would be giving us a headache - in the middle of the development stage :)

Comment: You got the answer right in your hands. Call those functions before and after the pertinent code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've kind of answered your own question. To do it for a specific file, error_reporting(0); will turn off errors. You can also call it multiple times in a script, I think.

You can also use php exceptions to 'catch' errors over a block of code. For example:

```
try {
    // code to ignore errors for here
} catch {
    // you can output a custom error here, but putting nothing here will effectively mean errors are ignored for the try block
}
```

The script will continue running past the try block, even if there is an error within it. See the [PHP Manual Entry](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for more information.

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php

    // normal code

    // error_reporting returns the old error code
    $old_error_reporting = error_reporting(0);

    // your errorful code

    // reset error_reporting to its old value
    error_reporting($old_error_reporting);

    // normal code
```

Although it would be a good idea to fix what is actually causing the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the error reporting level during runtime:

```
<?

   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   ... some code ....

   error_reporting(0);

   ... some more code ....

   error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I know of no other way but I can't think of a case where this wouldn't be sufficient. Can you?

Comment: A buggy function that's gonna be called later on maybe?

Answer (score 0):

That's really a long time ago but someone like me would maybe use my answer.

When i need to do this kind of stuff, i just put @ before the variable in order to NOT display the errors coming from this variable.

example:

```
switch(@$var!="e") {

....

}
```