# How do you turn error logging off for specific file in php?

Tags: php

How do you turn error logging off for specific file in php?

I know that for not displaying the error you do

```
<?
error_reporting(0); // dont report/show errors
don't log errors; - // how to do that.
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP turn off errors - in one file only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893644/php-turn-off-errors-in-one-file-only)

Comment: I believe here is the answer to that question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893644/php-turn-off-errors-in-one-file-only][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893644/php-turn-off-errors-in-one-file-only

Comment: I am referring to error LOGGING not reporting (displaying). How to turn off error logging.

Comment: Check this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114054/store-php-errors-in-a-log-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ini_set('log_errors', 'off');
```

or in PHP.ini:

```
log_errors = off
```

Answer (score 1):

Error logging is controlled through the [`log_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) configuration setting, so you can turn it off with `ini_set('log_errors', false)` and then turn it on again at the end of the file (actually, saving the old value and reverting to that is better).

Note that this will only work for code that is executed once, not e.g. for code inside class methods.

Comment: Downvoter: please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting(0)` effectively [disables logging of the errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1911930/797303). If you want to log the errors, but don't display them, you should use

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // or whatever level of reporting you need
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: That's the problem error_reporting(0) in my case doesn't show errors (which is what i wanted) but logs them (which i don't want)

Comment: @Adrian Does error_reporting(E_ALL) shows the errors? It seems that you have "display_errors" set to "off" and the error_reporting() function is disabled. Add var_dump(error_reporting()) to see if the value is changed